# Error while updating 'end' in shadow node of type: BVLinearGradient

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get "Error while updating 'end' in shadow node of type: BVLinearGradient" error when i run my react native app and the error seems to emanate from my MainApplication.java file here is my code:

```
package com.*;

import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.wheelpicker.WheelPickerPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
  @Override
  public boolean isDebug() {
// Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  @Override
  public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    // Add the packages you require here.
    // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new WheelPickerPackage(),
      new VectorIconsPackage(),
      new SvgPackage(),
      new LinearGradientPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve this

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, do accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with the [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient). The issue is in open status. For the time being, there are 2 solutions-

1. Replace start with startPoint and end with endPoint props for `<LinearGradient`/>
2. Downgrade react-native version to 0.50.3

The details for this issue is below:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/246

Comment: for my case, it was put X and Y not just the Y as: `<LinearGradient start={{ x:0, y: 1 }} end={{ x:0, y: 0 }}>`